# c# DataTable to Typed Class

Tags: c#

I have a function that loads Order Detail that I am using across multiple applications.  I am rewriting it for better performance, and want to remove some pre-calculated values from the Stored procedure to only be calculated when needed since most of those are only used once and only in certain circumstances.  Seems silly to make the Stored procedure calculate those every time an order is loaded instead of on the fly when needed.
Anyway I have a custom class, i.e.

```
public class OrderDtl
{
    public int OrderNum;
    public string Name;
    public string ShipToAddress1;         
    public string ShipToAddress2;
    public string ShipToCity;
    public string ShipToState;
    public int OrderLineCount;  //Currently Equated in SP wnating to remove
    ... (For like 40 more variables)
}
```

There is then a Stored procedure that returns a single row DataTable.  Is there an easier way to store the DataTable Column data into the same-named variables than doing this:

```
DataRow DR = oDT.Rows[0];
OrderNum = Int32.Parse(DR["OrderNum].ToString());
ShipToName = DR["ShipToName"].ToString();
ShipToAddress1 = DR["ShipToAddress1"].ToString();
ShipToAddress2 = DR["ShipToAddress2"].ToString();
OrderLineCount = Int32.Parse(DR["OrderLineCount"].ToString());
... (For like 40 more columns)
```

In *most* cases this is a columnname to variable name direct conversion, Data Table ShipToAddress1 column gets directly assigned to the variable ShipToAddress1.  I was hoping to have a smaller load function that assigned all the direct convert columns and then I can handle the non-direct conversions and add the additional calculations for the one-off data to properties and sub functions.
As an example of the One-off calculations like OrderLineCount above, I don't want to equate that in the stored procedure, instead only equate it when needed based off the number of records loaded from a second Stored procedure with this type of function:

```
public int OrderLineCount
{
    get {return OrderLines.Length;}
}
```

Comment: Dapper could do this transparently if you don't go through a `DataTable` but consume the result directly (and use properties, of course -- most tools don't like public fields and you shouldn't either).

Comment: Dapper isn't something I have heard of, I tend to shy away from 3rd party libraries for "relatively simple" processes to avoid problems like the Java log4j vulnerability that went undetected for so long.  If I write it (Yes there might be a vulnerability) I know what it is doing every step of the way and is unique to my code.  Anyway, I will look into Dapper and its functionality and see if it helps.  (I am not saying this is the "Right" way of doing it, just my method so far).

Comment: I looked into Dapper and don't think I want to adopt this type of change at this time.  Too much of the existing code in this company is based in ADO and as Serge mentioned below, doesn't seem like changing this code to be EF at this time has a huge benefit without refactoring all other related code to use a similar approach which is too big of a project right now.  But I will keep it in mind for my next "ground up" project.  Thank you for the suggestion, just not the direction I would like to solve the issue at this time.

Comment: That's all well and good, but Dapper is a micro-ORM that has absolutely nothing to do with Entity Framework. Nor is any refactoring required if the `DataTable` doesn't leave the method that fills the class -- it's about as "pay as you go" as you can get. You're free to make whatever decisions you make, of course, but do so on the basis of accurate information. An easier way to do what you do would come down to using reflection over the individual properties; if you really don't want any third-party libraries and don't care much about speed, that would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

OrderDtl order = JArray.FromObject(oDT.Rows[0].Table)[0].ToObject<OrderDtl>();
```

and fix the class by adding getters/setters

```
public class OrderDtl
{
    public int OrderNum {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set; }

  // ... and so on
  
}
```

you can also add [JsonProperty] attribute if a name of column differs from the property name

Comment: This is a quick and dirty way that's doable for a single object, but it's worth noting that storing the result in a `DataTable` which is then turned into a JSON array which is in turn parsed back into an `object` is inefficient, and scales poorly as a general technique. If you're going to be pulling in third-party libraries anyway, may as well use Dapper to deserialize the data directly from a result set without any of these intermediates.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You have to tell OP about it. Op has a table already and wants to convert it to a typed class. What are you going to tell him not to do this? It is not your bussiness.

Comment: I'm not telling anyone to do anything, but pointing out a potential problem with this approach. Per the OP's question, a stored procedure is being used to produce this `DataTable`, and then using a `DataTable` is not necessary. If the `DataTable` appeared out of thin air somewhere with no alternative but to use it, it might be a different matter.

Comment: @JeroenMostert  I don't see any code how the table was created, I don't know whe have you found a stored procedure here, and OP didn't ask how to bring data from db.

Comment: From the question: "There is then a Stored procedure that returns a single row DataTable."

Comment: No need to argue.  It is a good point about using a DataTable if it isn't necessary, it has just been what I have always used to consume SQL Data into C# code when there are multiple columns and rows.  Parsing the DataTable after the connection to SQL is closed just always seemed the best method for me to use.  I am open to alternates, though Data Contention is very high on my radar since I am querying from my ERP and never writing data back though the connection.

Comment: @JeroenMostert some peope just prefer good old ADO.net  instead  of EF. I used ADO.net  alot too and I don't see any sense and need to  use Dapper.